# New row which is the difference of two rows using Groupby in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, difference-between-rows

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
'value': [100, 120, 130, 200, 190, 210],
'value2': [2100, 2120, 2130, 2200, 2190, 2210],   
'state': ['init','mid', 'final', 'init', 'mid', 'final'], 
})
```

I want to add another row, which is the difference of 'final' and 'init' in the state column for each ID.

The result should look like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2], 
    'value': [100, 120, 130, 200, 190, 210, 30, 10],
    'value2': [2100, 2120, 2130, 2200, 2190, 2210, 100, 10],   
     'state': ['init','mid', 'final', 'init', 'mid', 'final', 'diff', 'diff'], 
 })
```

I have tried the following. But I get AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'groupby' error

```
df1 = df.copy()

df1 = df[df.state.isin(['final', 'init'])].copy
s = df1.groupby('ID', sort=False).diff().dropna.assign(id=df1['ID'].unique(), state='diff')
df = df.append(s, sort=True).sort_values("ID")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this? Group by `ID`, keep only the `value*` cols, take the diff, and reassign `ID` and `state`:

```py
df
```

|  | ID | value | value2 | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 100 | 2100 | init |
| 1 | 1 | 120 | 2120 | mid |
| 2 | 1 | 130 | 2130 | final |
| 3 | 2 | 200 | 2200 | init |
| 4 | 2 | 190 | 2190 | mid |
| 5 | 2 | 210 | 2210 | final |

```py
diffs = (df[df.state.isin(['init', 'final'])]
    .groupby('ID')[['value', 'value2']]
    .diff().dropna()
    .assign(ID=df.ID.unique(), state='diff')
)
```

|  | ID | value | value2 | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 30.0 | 30.0 | diff |
| 1 | 2 | 10.0 | 10.0 | diff |

Then combine back into `df`:

```py
df = df.append(diffs)
```

|  | ID | value | value2 | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 100.0 | 2100.0 | init |
| 1 | 1 | 120.0 | 2120.0 | mid |
| 2 | 1 | 130.0 | 2130.0 | final |
| 3 | 2 | 200.0 | 2200.0 | init |
| 4 | 2 | 190.0 | 2190.0 | mid |
| 5 | 2 | 210.0 | 2210.0 | final |
| 0 | 1 | 30.0 | 30.0 | diff |
| 1 | 2 | 10.0 | 10.0 | diff |

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to take the difference betweent the `final` state and the `init` as a matrix operation and then fill the missing columns `ID` and `state` passing a dictionary of values.

```
val_cols = ['value', 'value2']
df_final = df.query('state == "final"')[val_cols].reset_index(drop=True) - df.query('state== "init"')[val_cols].reset_index(drop=True)

df_final = pd.concat([df, df_final])

values = {'ID': {i:i+1 for i, v in enumerate(df.ID.unique())}, 'state': 'diff'}
df_final.fillna(values, inplace=True)
```

**Final Result**

[image]

Comment: This solution works well in this example. But if the IDs were not non numeric or were not sequentially arranged, values = {'ID': {i:i+1 for i, v in enumerate(df.ID.unique())}, 'state': 'diff'} does not give the right output for ID / group. How might one fix that?

Comment: yes @postcolonialist, in that case sorting `df_final` by id and state before applying the operations should work